# Python (matplotlib): how to flip negative bars from upside down to upright in a bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

Thanks to the many resources on stack overflow and on the web, I have been able to create a graph that looks similar to this (this is a google image not my graph) using matplotlib.

[Grouped bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEzSP.png)

[image]

Now, I want to know if it is possible to have all the bars in an upright position. Because the main purpose of the graphical representation is to visually compare different values for each group, but it is not visually appealing or convenient to make comparisons when some groups are upside down.

Please how can I flip the negative bars from upside down to upright position so that my graph can look like this?

[upright grouped bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q7cK.png)

[image]

Furthermore, I have a tab delimited table that looks like this.

```
Students Grade Eat Sleep Score Label
Ali       A    -0.5 0.09  2.1   M
Ryan      B    0.01 -1.1 -0.08  C
Ben       C    0.76 7.5 -0.0001 M
Eyr       A    0.5  0.9  -0.087 M
Tify      A   -0.09 -0.08 0.987 M
Nola      B   -0.5  0.03  1.18  M
West      C    1.2  1.3  -0.76  C
Nile      C    0.2  0.07 -1.09  C
```

[file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XBqI.png)

[image]

I created a pandas dataframe and I have been able to plot specific rows from the table by calling:

```
l1 = df[(df['Grade'] == 'A') & (df['Label'] == 'M')]
```

I have a very large data and I would like to have more information in one graph to save space. How can I display multiple information in one graph, for example where Grade = A, Grade = C and label = M. So, I want a graph that will display values for Grade = C and label = M as well as Grade = A and label = M.

Comment: The question is relatively unclear; why don't you just take the absolute value of your data before plotting? That will "flip the negative bars from upside down to upright position".

Comment: I want it to be a simple bar chart with negative and positive values placed on top of the X axis. If I take the absolute, won't the values on the y-axis change?

Comment: @Cave, could you post your sample data as a text, so we could copy it?

Comment: @MaxU, Ok but I don't know how to post a table so I posted it as a code.

Answer (score 1):

Small Demo:

Sample DF:

```
In [71]: df
Out[71]:
     A
0  100
1  -20
2  130
3  200
4  -80

In [72]: df['A'].plot.bar(grid=True)
Out[72]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xdff9198>
```

[image]

Solution:

```
In [75]: ax = df.assign(X=df['A'] + abs(df['A'].min()))['X'].plot.bar(grid=True)
```

intermediate result:

[image]

```
In [76]: new = [int(l.get_text()) + df['A'].min() if l.get_text().isdigit() else l.get_text()  for l in ax.get_yticklabels()]

In [77]: ax.set_yticklabels(new)
Out[77]:
[<matplotlib.text.Text at 0xdfa6a20>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0xd11cfd0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0xe25c240>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0xe25cdd8>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0xe269630>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0xe269e48>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0xd06b198>]
```

after "fixing" y-ticks labels:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! May I ask why the fifth bar at position 4 disappeared?